# Angular Router anchorScrolling fragment not creating a proper URL

Tags: angular, angular-router

I followed this tutorial here for anchor scrolling in Angular 7+ [Here](https://www.bennadel.com/blog/3545-enabling-the-second-click-of-a-routerlink-fragment-using-onsameurlnavigation-reload-in-angular-7-1-3.htm).

My anchors to not function properly because of the URLs the router generates from the fragment provided.

I added the necessary options to my router:

```
@NgModule({
imports: [
RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {
  useHash: true,
  anchorScrolling: "enabled",
  onSameUrlNavigation: "reload",
  scrollPositionRestoration: "enabled"
})
],
exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

Then I have this on my template:

```
<a routerLink="." fragment="hw">Hello World Jump</a>

<!-- Some content here. -->

<mat-card>
   <h1 id="hw">Hello World</h1>
</mat-card>
```

When clicking the link, I get this URL: 
**http://localhost:4200/#/#import**
Which does not even contain my routed page.

If I remove `useHash: true,` I get this link:
**http://localhost:4200/landing-page#import**
Which is not correct either. I am missing a / in between the page and the anchor ID.

When I try to add it, it gets removed by the router.

Answer (score 1):

The second one that you are getting is correct. There is no / before anchor tag. Same is mentioned in angular official guide 
https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLink